# Data factory web GUI - set type parameter in copy activity mapping

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How do I set the datatype with GUI in Azure Data Factory: 
[image]

Alternatively, how do I specify the mapping as dynamic content?

I have a REST service as Source and I get this error message when I try to auto-generate schema mapping:

> 'Failed to generate unified schema from hierarchical data. Exception
>   message: Failed to convert the value in 'relativeUrl' property to
>   'System.String' type.'

The value of the relativeUrl is a string, I have tried with an absolute url, relative url, with and without parameter mappings.

Comment: Both questions are relevant for me too: How do you edit the type in the GUI? How do you trouble-shoot failures in "Import schema"?

Comment: Never found a good solution to this. I have now moved the solution to use Data flow preview for mapping and created a temporary table that I simply store the data fetched raw from API instead of using the mapping.

Comment: We went the other way and coded the mapping directly in JSON. There is a risk of the GUI overwriting the changes when updating something else, but the pipelines in question are now very stable and not changed. Added some internal documentation to help the next guy.